# Search for drive items with $expand parameter

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying serach in a drive for **driveItems**. I have figured out how to search for **driveItems** in the API like this:

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/search(q='test')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteId%7D/drives/%7BdriveId%7D/search(q=%27test%27))

But for my application, I need **more detailed information about the documents** so I tried to use the **$expand** without any successful outcome.

Request to look up more details about a single **driveItem**:

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/listItem/?expand=fields($select=Title,ID,etc..)](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteID%7D/drives/%7BdriveId%7D/items/%7BitemId%7D/listItem/?expand=fields($select=Title,ID,etc..))

Is it possible to achieve all the fields I get from this request when I use the **$expand** parameter in [Search for DriveItems within a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? Or do I need to look up every single **driveItem** to get the additional parameters?

**What I have tried:**

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/search(q='test')?expand=fields($select=id,title,etc..)](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteId%7D/drives/%7BdriveId%7D/search(q=%27test%27)?expand=fields($select=id,title,etc..))

Comment: You are searching for `driveItems` and you want to include details about related `listItem`. It should be possible with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/search(q='test')?$expand=listItem` but expanding `listItem` relationship doesn't work with the search operation according to this ticket: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4604

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, unfortunately, when I use the following graph api:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/?$expand=fields($select=id)
```

I got the error：

> "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'fields' on type 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'."

If you want to use the `$expend` parameter, I suggest you use the following Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/?$expand=fields($select=id)
```